# Getting a reference to an instantiating object from the parameter object

Tags: java, containers, jcomponent

I instantiate two dependent classes:

```
//Create and set up the content pane.
ImportTablePanel surveyTablePanel = new ImportTablePanel(genErrorDescArray); 

SurveyTree surveyTreePanel = new SurveyTree(surveyTablePanel,genErrorDescArray);
```

The SurveyTree class has a method **setImportOK()** that I wish to access from the ImportTablePanel class.

```
public class SurveyTree extends JPanel 
                      implements TreeSelectionListener  {
```

...

```
public void setImportOK(){
// my code here
}
```

The problem I have is that instantiation of a SurveyTree object takes the ImportTablePanel as a parameter. This makes it very difficult to get a reference to the SurveyTree object.

After many attempts, I finally have managed to get this to work by navigating upwards from the table container - see code below.
I am sure there is a much better way to get a container reference - ideally something like `table.getContainer(int indexFromTop)` **can anyone make a suggestion?**

```
public class ImportTablePanel extends JPanel implements TableModelListener {

...

 SurveyTree  surveyTree = (SurveyTree) table.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
 surveyTree.setImportOK();

}
```

Many thanks..

In the end I used a singleton design pattern.

```
public class SwingUtility {

private static SwingUtility instance;
private static SurveyTree surveyTreePanel;

SwingUtility() {

}

public static synchronized SwingUtility getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new SwingUtility();
    }
    return instance;
}

public SurveyTree getSurveyTreePanel() {
    return surveyTreePanel;
}

public void setSurveyTreePanel(SurveyTree surveyTreePanel) {
    SwingUtility.surveyTreePanel = surveyTreePanel;
}
```

}

create singleton instance with main method

```
// set up singleton instance of survey form
    SwingUtility swingUtility = new SwingUtility();
    swingUtility.setSurveyTreePanel(surveyTreePanel);
```

Then reference the SurveyTree from the Import Table Panel

```
 SurveyTree surveyForm =   SwingUtility.getInstance().getSurveyTreePanel();
 surveyForm.setImportOK();
```

Comment: `table.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent()`   => at least a for loop ?

Comment: I think you should reevaluate your class structure. Under your current model, `surveyTablePanel` really shouldn't be aware of the existence of `surveyTreePanel`. Does `setImportOK()` really need to be accessed inside `surveyTablePanel`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful advice - I re-designed as you suggested.. however kept with orig methods